# Put List into Bundle object

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bundle

I want to add a `List<CustomObject>` into a `Bundle` object.
This `CustomObject` implements the `Parcelable` interface. I've noticed that the Bundle object has a class that is hidden that allowed me to pass a `List` of objects.

```
/** {@hide} */
    @UnsupportedAppUsage
    public void putParcelableList(String key, List<? extends Parcelable> value) {
        unparcel();
        mMap.put(key, value);
        mFlags &= ~FLAG_HAS_FDS_KNOWN;
    }
```

However as we can see is hidden. How can I pass a `List` of `CustomObject`s? or how can I transform a list into an `ArrayList` using Kotlin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can transform list into Array using this code

```
val arrayList = ArrayList(list)
```

Answer (score 5):

> how can I transform a list into an ArrayList using Kotlin?

Just cast as `ArrayList`

```
val bundle = Bundle()
val list : List<CustomObject > = ArrayList<CustomObject>()
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("list", list as ArrayList<CustomObject>)
```

Comment: This throws an exception when the list only contains one item. e.g. `listOf("one") as ArrayList<String>`